# SQL Count Query for asset inventory database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently making a database for simple inventory asset tracking. I want to have an audit feature which will count the number of desktops, monitors, and phones in a cube(cubicle). I don't know a whole lot about SQL and this is my first project working with MSSQL. The database is one table and has no relations as of yet. I have a column called devicetype which stores either DESKTOP, MONITOR, PHONE, ETC. I need a way to count each device type for a cube. my primary key is the asset tag. my thought process is this:

```
select Count(monitor,phone,desktop per cube)
from table
having count(devicetype.desktop>1), count(devicetype.phone>1), Count(devicetype.monitor>2).
```

I know this is not how you write it, this is to just kinda explain what i think should happen. basically there should only be 1 desktop asset, 1 phone asset, and 2 monitor assets per cube. And i want the query to tell me all the cubes that don't follow those rules so we can go manually check them. I'm not sure if my database is set up correctly to do this or not and i don't know enough about queries to make this happen. Any help, thoughts, or questions would be amazing. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Updated with sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Select [cube],
       sum(case when devicetype = 'monitor' then 1 else 0 end) as num_monitors,
       sum(case when devicetype = 'phone' then 1 else 0 end) as num_phones,
       sum(case when devicetype = 'desktop' then 1 else 0 end) as num_desktops
from sampledata
group by [cube]
having sum(case when devicetype = 'monitor' then 1 else 0 end)  <> 1 or
       sum(case when devicetype = 'phone' then 1 else 0 end) <> 1 or
       sum(case when devicetype = 'desktop' then 1 else 0 end) <> 2;
```

`cube` is a poor name for a column because it is a SQL Server reserved word.  That means that it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! this works great when i add a where statement for the cube. but how would i get it to loop through all the cubes. Also, could you explain the `then 1 else 0 end` part

Comment: This gives me a syntax error: Incorrect syntax near 'having'. expected '('. And then it says invalid column names after the Having part.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon! this worked perfectly, I did not realize that was a reserved word. I ended up having to +1 the values. It ended up looking like this:

```
Select [cube],
       sum(case when devicetype = 'monitor' then 1 else 0 end) as num_monitors,
       sum(case when devicetype = 'phone' then 1 else 0 end) as num_phones,
       sum(case when devicetype = 'desktop' then 1 else 0 end) as num_desktops
from table
group by [cube]
having sum(case when devicetype = 'monitor' then 1 else 0 end)  > 2 or
       sum(case when devicetype = 'phone' then 1 else 0 end) > 2 or
       sum(case when devicetype = 'desktop' then 1 else 0 end) > 3;
```